# symfony blank bundle class loader

Tags: php, class, symfony, bundle

I can't figure out why does symfony2 load's a blank class for a Bundle like this :
AppKernel.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        );
```

Like the last line `new AppBundle\AppBundle()`

The `src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php` looks like this :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

I really dont understand. I read both Symfony2 books (the book and the cookbook) and I couldn't find an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not really a blank class. It extends the base Bundle class and this provides the functionality that Symfony needs to register a bundle

Comment: But why does it need to register the bundle? What do you mean by registering the bundle? Why can't i just use the blank controller and method? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: Symfony needs to register the bundle so that the kernel is aware of its existence and of all the code it includes like controllers, etc... Read the docs!

Comment: you need to reread the book if youre not sure on that.   It has to be an extension of the bundle class in order to inherit all the functionality it needs. Symfony needs packages to be organised into bundles in order to know where to find everything.  You can put your 'blank' controller into that bundle, while observing the proper folder structure.

Comment: But why then I need to define the route with the `@AppBundle` (from the book it said that `@AppBundle` translate to /src/AppBundle/). The route file already knows where to find my Controller so why does symfony2 need to define an empty class if it already knows where are my controllers). I need to figure out the internal work of this.